# Passing struct to a callback function

Tags: c, linux, gtk, glib

I'm trying to pass multiple variables (gtkentry and FILE):

```
struct data callback_params;
callback_params.entry = gtk_entry_new();
callback_params.file = config_file;
gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(content_area), callback_params.entry);
g_signal_connect(dialog,"response",G_CALLBACK (add_new_set),&callback_params);

void add_new_set(GtkDialog *dialog, gint response_id, gpointer callback_params)
{
    g_print(gtk_entry_get_text(callback_params.entry));
}
```

When compiling, I get the following error:

```
file.h:7:45: error: request for member 'entry' in something not a structure or union
    g_print(gtk_entry_get_text(callback_params.entry));
```

Do I need to cast the `gpointer`?

Comment: And the definition of `gpointer` is?

Comment: pointer and I'm not seeing where you are going with this

Comment: Yes you need to cast the `gpointer`. `gpointer` is an *untyped* pointer; it doesn't know what it contains. You are giving it a pointer to a `struct data`, so you have to cast it back to a `struct data *`. Also in C and C++ the operator for accessing the member of a pointer to a structure is `->`, not `.` as it is for normal structures.

Comment: Could you post the portion of your code that is calling the function `add_new_set() `?

Answer (score 0):

You're converting between incompatible types. Assuming that you're using GTK, the prototype for `gtk_entry_get_text()` is:

```
const gchar * gtk_entry_get_text (GtkEntry *entry);
```

Meanwhile, your function declares a `gpointer`, which `glib` translates to:

```
typedef void* gpointer;
```

In other words, you are trying to access a member of a `void` pointer. The compiler can't calculate the offset or type of what you want, so it throws an error.

What you need to do is to cast the `gpointer` to the appropriate type, and then access it as a pointer to a structure Here's an example of how to do that with your current function:

```
void add_new_set (GtkDialog *dialog, gint response_id, gpointer callback_params) {
    g_print (gtk_entry_get_text (((struct data *) callback_params)->entry));
}
```

Here, the `struct data *` casts the void pointer to a pointer to a `struct` of type `data`, after which the `->` dereferences the pointer and returns the appropriate field.

Comment: I got the following:
(tat:14122): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_entry_get_text: assertion 'GTK_IS_ENTRY (entry)' failed

(tat:14122): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_print: assertion 'format != NULL' failed

and nothign is printed